# Not smooth in corners mesh topology

Tags: mesh, smooth

I made the mesh by bridging two meshes. Both meshes have the same number of edges and are connected correctly. I applied auto-smooth shading and tried to use the subdivision modifier, but nothing helped me avoid sharper parts on the corner. What is the best practice to make meshes more smooth except auto-smooth shading?

UPD: I understand that the problem starts from my two meshes. I want to connect with different round-corner options (distance between the edges). But I don't know how I can fix it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: "What is the best practice to make meshes more smooth except auto-smooth shading?"  A combination of two things: 1) use good topo (here, your faces are strongly non-planar considering their size); 2) use fewer vertices.  Your shape is a curved box.  So make a box, and make it curved only via subdivision.  Gotta also say, looks like you're bevelling boundary edges, no idea what the plan is there or what a bevel will do with that.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the subdivision modofier? I can't understand how to make the ellipse with different round corners from a rectangle face.

Comment: The ellipse can be a stretched hexagon.

Comment: Thanks for all I found the decision!